# SAS for Blob write access keeps causing 403 authentication error with azure storage

Tags: .net, azure, key, storage, blob

I keep getting a 403 authentication error from the Azure Storage Service when I try to use a SAS key I generated using the azure client storage library.  The exception is being thrown on the calling code.

**Here is the exception I'm getting:**

```
StatusMessage:Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of
Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
ErrorCode:AuthenticationFailed
```

**Here's the SAS key being generated (the signature at the end is not accurate since I didn't want to share that):**

```
https://evinsight.blob.core.windows.net/jimsworld/jellyfish2.png?sv=2012-02-12&se=2013-08-29T03%3A36%3A52Z&sr=b&sp=w&sig=FJALKJFLKASJDF%JLKSDJLK%LJDLFKSDFJKL
```

**Here is the calling code:**

```
/// Create the document and file objects and then return the fileAccessToken
/// <param name = "file_name"></param> */
public void GetSasInfoFromEb(string file_name)
{
    /*********************************** EVINSIGHT TESTING CODE ********************************************/
    try
    {
        AzureStorageTester ast = new AzureStorageTester();
        BlobSasUri = ast.getStorageLibrarySas(file_name);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    /***************************************************************************************************************/
}

/// Sends the whole small file to Azure Blob
public void WriteSmallFileToBlob()
{
    int fileId = 0;
    try
    {
        Blob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(BlobSasUri));
        Blob.UploadFromStream(File.InputStream);


        File.InputStream.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

**Here's is the SAS generating code:**

```
    /// <summary>
    ///  Returns the URI similar to how eB does it
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="blobName">The name of the file being uploaded/downloaded</param>
    /// <returns>The full uri for blob access</returns>
    public string getStorageLibrarySas(string blobName)
    {
        string sasKey;
        string uri;

        setupBlobContainer();

        blobName = blobName.ToLower();
        _blob = _cloudRootContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);


        sasKey = _blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
        {
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write,
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
        });

        return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}{1}", _blob.Uri, sasKey);
    }

    /// Creates the Blob Container
    private void setupBlobContainer()
    {
        try
        {
            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials credentials = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(_accountName, _accountKey);

            // Create the storage account with the connection string
            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount _cloudStorageAccount = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);

            _cloudBlobClient = _cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            _cloudRootContainer = _cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(_rootPath.ToLower());
            _cloudRootContainer.CreateIfNotExists();

            BlobContainerPermissions containerPermissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();


            containerPermissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Off;
            _cloudRootContainer.SetPermissions(containerPermissions);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?  Appreciate it!

Comment: Where are you getting the exception? In the code above, or in the calling app trying to use one of your SAS URI's? If the latter, I can take a pretty good guess that it's related to clock-drift. If the former, please point out where the exception is occurring.

Comment: The exception is being thrown on the calling code trying to use the SAS. The server is basically rejecting the SAS key. I left out the start time, shouldn't that take care of the clock skew issue?

Comment: Can you trace the request/response through Fiddler? You should get more information about 403 error that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue I was having centered on the creation of the CONTAINER with the CLIENT.  There are two different azure storage libraries (storage and StorageClient).  I was using code for storage but using the old StorageClient approach in which you pass in the full path into the client object "getref..." method to get the container.  It turns out the 2.0 storage library requires that you only pass in the container NAME to get the container.  These two different libraries, with the same naming for everything, have really made things confusing.

Answer (score 4):

Your code looks perfectly fine to me. In fact, I used your code to create a sample application and everything worked well.

Can you please check the **`sig`** part of the SAS token? Especially look for **`+`** sign there. I have seen a similar issue here not too long ago where occasionally SAS URL was failing with 403 error. It turned out the SAS token has a plus sign in it which is URL encoded value for **`space`**. Since the SAS token is sent as URL, `+` sign in the token was interpreted as space and resulted in 403 error.

Answer (score 3):

The StartTime is a common cause of this error (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/08/28/http-403-server-failed-to-authenticate-the-request-when-using-shared-access-signatures.aspx), but since you are not specifying the start time I suspect you are hitting the other common cause of this error - an incorrect URI.  See [When using Shared Access Signature (SAS) with Windows Azure, it is best to use Uri.AbsoluteUri() instead of Uri.ToString().](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/06/17/when-using-shared-access-signature-sas-with-windows-azure-it-is-best-to-use-uri-absoluteuri-instead-of-uri-tostring.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Per comments, let me post this as a suggested answer: It's likely that you're seeing clock skew. Try setting the SAS start time to, say, a minute earlier than current time. By default, start time is set to current start time (of the server generating the SAS). The time setting could be slightly off from the storage system's clock.

Comment: I tried setting the start time to -10, but I still get the 403 authentication error.

Comment: Here's the exception that I'm getting:  StatusMessage:Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of
Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
ErrorCode:AuthenticationFailed